# CSS transition: control other div

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have a CSS transition that increases the size of an element upon hovering but I would also like it to control the corresponding text.  Will I need to use jQuery?  I tried the `<div1> + <div2> {}` notation but had no luck.

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qE9kJ/194/)

```
<div class="row glyph-belt">
<div class="rectangle-container col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div id="rectangle"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="glyph-title-row">

        <div class="col-xs-3 circle-1">
            <div class="container circle-container">
                <i class="icon-steak glyph-custom" style="font-size: 60px"></i>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 circle-2">
            <div class="container circle-container">
                <i class="icon-brain glyph-custom" style="font-size: 60px"></i>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-3 circle-3">
            <div class="container circle-container">
                <i class="icon-happy glyph-custom" style="font-size: 60px"></i>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row glyph-title-row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 glyph-title-container glyph-title-container-1">Blah blah blah</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 glyph-title-container glyph-title-container-2">blah Blah blah</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 glyph-title-container glyph-title-container-3">blah blah Blah</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add a piece of the `css` and `html` so we get a better understanding of the structure it has to apply to.

Comment: Is corresponding text that text above image and what you want do to with it?

Comment: I would like the text to scale in the same manner as the circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/qE9kJ/196/

JS

```
$('.circle-1').hover(function() {
    $('.glyph-title-container-1').toggleClass('big-font');
});

$('.circle-2').hover(function() {
    $('.glyph-title-container-2').toggleClass('big-font');
});

$('.circle-3').hover(function() {
    $('.glyph-title-container-3').toggleClass('big-font');
});
```

CSS

```
.big-font {
  font-size: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.glyph-title-container {
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to control consecutive sibling using the `+` selector notation as you mentioned.

If you rearrange your HTML such that it looks something like this:

```
 <div class="container circle-container circle-1">
     <i class="icon-star" style="font-size: 60px"></i>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3 glyph-title-container glyph-title-container-1">
     Real Food. Real Weightloss.
 </div>
```

However, rearranging your HTML will mean you have to redo a lot of the CSS to regain the desired appearance.

You can get both items to transform smoothly on hover with the following CSS:

```
.circle-container:hover,
.circle-container:hover + .glyph-title-container {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
    -o-transform: scale(1.25);
    transform: scale(1.25);
}
.circle-container,
.glyph-title-container {
    -webkit-transition: transition .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: transition .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transition .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: transition .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery will make it easier. (God, it has been a long time for me not writing jQuery...)

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qE9kJ/198/).

Simply add the code below to your JavaScript code:

```
$('.circle-container').hover(function () {
  i = $(this).index() - 1;
  $($('.glyph-title-row div')[i])
    .css('color', 'blue');
}, function () {
  $($('.glyph-title-row div')[i])
    .css('color', 'black');
});
```